# Socket.io chat example handshake failed from iOS

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to create a native iOS client for the chat example in Socket.io.

I've set up everything, but at this point...

```
[socketIO connectToHost:@"localhost" onPort:3000];
```

I get this error

```
ERROR: handshake failed ... Server returned status code 400
```

I guess I have to send some params, maybe like this...

```
[socketIO connectToHost:@"localhost" onPort:3000 withParams:...];
```

...but I have no idea what I have to send.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a client library like [https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc)? Anyway, here are some details on doing the connection yourself: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec

Comment: Hey what is the result?

Comment: Let me know any one if you have any solution for this. Currently i come to know that issue is due to new version(1.0) at server side yet not supported so need to reinstall to last version of (0.9) : https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc/issues/191

Comment: Try adding http in the host and see if it's working.

Comment: Which version of Socket.io are you running on your server?

Comment: SocketIO released their own client in swift so if you are just messing around you could use theirs in swift which is compatible with 1.0+ https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

Comment: do not forget that Http Status Code 400 is `Bade Request`. read documents and required params.